# Stupid IE not showing selected value in combo box

Tags: internet-explorer, combobox, selectedvalue

I am facing a weird problem in IE which is not happening with other browsers. Open the following website:

http://www.clinicasdefertilidadenlima.pe/

You will see 3 combo boxes on this page displaying "Lima". Click on any combo and select any other value like Lima or Arequipa. Page will refresh but now combo will not show selected value which should always be "Lima" (I have hard coded it)
If you take a look at the view source then it's a simple combo box and I have even defined selected="selected" for "Lima" value but in IE it only displays selected value when you open home page. After that it doesn't show value when you select value from combo box.

```
<select id="city_id" name="city_id" class="f2_city" onchange="redirect(this.form)">
    <option value="" selected="selected">LIMA</option>
    <option value="LIMA">LIMA</option>
    <option value="Arequipa">Arequipa</option>
</select>
```

I am using IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. Just defined this in page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved using the jquery n-th:child selector that works on IE7/8/9 Chrome/Firefox etc.

```
var comboId = document.getElementById('YourDropDownListId');
var selectedIndex = comboId.selectedIndex;
var selector = '#TableName:nth-child(' + selectedIndex.toString() + ')';
var selectedTable = $(selector).val();
```