# Combo box isn't set with loaded value from server - IE (ASP.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

I've been looking for an answer for my question, but non of the posts here helped me to solve the problem.
I have an ASP.net razor application. My view contains several combo boxes which must be value set by a loaded object from the server.
Everything works perfect when using Chrome. However, when I'm trying to do it in IE, well... non of the values is set to the combo boxes (note, their inner lists are populated. only the value to be set isn't really set although the js code handles it).
I tried several things such as the meta tag but nothing worked.

Can someone assist with this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Show us some code.

Comment: Well, I found a definition such as <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>. I tried several variations of meta tag. Assigning the value is performed by document.getElementById('myCombo').value = myValue; Nothing really special.

Comment: I also tried the suggestions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508399/stupid-ie-not-showing-selected-value-in-combo-box

Comment: You should post some code, just like the question you mentioned.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using `getElementById`? `$('#myCombo').val(myValue)`

Comment: @Tieson T, I tried it... still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to change the selected value in a `select` element, you need to trigger the `change` event after setting it's value. Otherwise, the visibly-selected item will not change.

```
$('#myCombo').val(myValue).change();
```